# How to calculate combinations if one of the numbers is negative?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I know that you can easily calculate $_5C_3$ to be $\frac{5!}{3!2!}=10$. However, what about $_5C_{-3}$, for example?  It surely wouldn't work out using the combinations formula as it would involve a negative factorial. Do we just say something like $_5C_{-3}=0$? Google's built in calculator says so.

Comment: The binomial coefficient $\binom n k$ is *defined* as being $0$ when $k < 0$ or $k > n$.

Comment: @PrimeMover Though with the definition $\binom nk=\frac1{k!}\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}n-j$ the fact that $\binom nk=0$ for $n\in\Bbb N$ and $k>n$ is actually a theorem.

Comment: @PrimeMover I see. I was just split between whether it would be undefined or 0.

Comment: And $\binom nk\ne0$ for $n\notin\mathbb N$ (assuming $k\in\mathbb N$) regardless of whether $n$ is greater than $k$, less than $k$, negative, or imaginary. The $k^\text{th}$ degree polynomial $\binom zk$ has only $k$ zeroes, namely $z=0,1,2,\dots,k-1$.

Comment: @Gae.S. Trouble with that is you have to be extra careful about how you define $k!$ for negative $k$. Not saying your statement is wrong as such, more that it raises extra complications that need more explanation to ensure it is rigorous. Also bear in mind that a vacuous product is taken to be $1$ not $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How many ways can you pick a negative number of things from a set of objects?

It is impossible. There are none, so the value of the choose function is zero.